# Can't write animation code in separate function, tkinter

Tags: python, function, class, animation, tkinter

I have the following code in which I make many instances of a class Display and then in each class I call the function display, which displays the data

```
from tkinter import *

class Display:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def display(self):
        canvas.create_oval(self.x,self.y,self.x+10,self.y+10,fill="lime")

def show(inst):    
    makeFun = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(makeFun, width=800, height=700)
    makeFun.title("Test Evolution")
    canvas.pack()

    instance = [Display(random.randrange(300,700),random.randrange(300,700)) for a in range(inst)]

    for a in range(inst):
        instance[a].display()

    canvas.mainloop()
```

But when I call the function...

```
show(10)
```

it returns an error saying:

```
NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined
```

Comment: variable created in function are `local` and you can't access it in ohter function. In class you shoudl use `self.canvas` but first you should sent canvas to class - `__init__(self, canvas, x, y)__: self.canvas = canvas`. OR use `def display(self, canvas):`

Comment: BT:W instead of `for a in range(inst): instance[a].dosplay()` you should use `for item in instance: item.display()` - it is prefered in Python because it is more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable created in function is `local` and you can't access it in other function so you should send it as argument

```
def display(self, canvas):
```

and

```
item.display(canvas)
```

---

BTW: name `Item` better fit to this class because it is item/object which you will display.

You could use preferred method to work with list - without `range()`

```
    for item in instances:
        item.display(canvas)
```

---

Full working example

```
import tkinter as tk # `import *` is not preferred
import random

class Item:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def display(self, canvas):
        canvas.create_oval(self.x, self.y, self.x+10, self.y+10, fill="lime")

def show(inst):    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Test Evolution")

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=700)
    canvas.pack()

    instances = [Item(random.randrange(300,700),random.randrange(300,700)) for a in range(inst)]

    for item in instances:
        item.display(canvas)

    root.mainloop()

show(100)
```